# ng-repeat multiples valores

Tags: angularjs

Supongamos que tengo:

`Columns` es un *array* de un objeto `Column = {name, tipo}`

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns"> => esto iterara 4 veces por ejm:
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model=""/>
 <select>
        <option value="mayor">Mayor que</option>
        <option value="menor">Menor que</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" ng-model=""/>
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="getValues()" />
```

Como podría obtener los valores solo los que el `check` están marcados?, es decir, si se repite 4 veces y he marcado check solo el segundo y cuarto y tener su valor del `check`, del `select` y del `text` de cada uno?, es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He modificado lo sgte, he añadido al controlador el array, y tb el each :

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns"> => esto iterara 4 veces por ejm:
 <input type="checkbox" value="{{column.field}}" ng-value="column.field" 
 ng-model="modelo_dinamico[column.type]"/>
 <select>
    <option value="mayor">Mayor que</option>
    <option value="menor">Menor que</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" ng-model=""/>
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="getValues()" />
```

y en el index.html tengo :

Mostrar valores : {{modelo_dinamico}}  => resultado : "[]", si llamo a la funcion getValues no me parece nada.

Pero yo no solo quiero el valor del checkbox, sino tb q tendra asociado el select y el input text.

Por lo tanto, para que funcione he tenido que hacer esto :

$scope.modelo_dinamico = {};

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{column.field}}" ng-value="column.field" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[column.field].check"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[column.field].text"/>
```

y esto ya me da :

modelo_dinamico : {"id":{"check":true},"nombre":{"check":true,"select":"mayor","text":"66"},"precio":{"check":true,"text":"77","select":"menor"},"cantidad":{"check":false}}

Comment: estoy trabajando en eso, para ayudarte para todos los campos, apenas lo tenga actualizo!

Comment: @sioesi ya lo tengo, esa es la solución, lo explico mas abajo.

Comment: Jose, actualice @Jose

Answer (score 0):

actualmente en angularjs no esta soportado los `ng-models` dinamicos (como es tu caso) lo que te recomiendo hacer es en tu controlador definir un arreglo vacio :

```
$scope.modelo_dinamico = [];
```

Recorrer tu arreglo de objetos Column

```
angular.forEach($scope.columns, function(columna, index){
    $scope.modelo_dinamico[columna.tipo] = "";
})
```

Dandole al arreglo vacio que declaramos `index` que son unicos ya que son iguales a las `id` de tus columnas, si imprimes este valor quedaria

```
tipo_1 : "",
tipo_2 : "",
tipo_3 : ""
```

Suponiendo que las tipos son tipo_1, tipo_2 y tipo_3.

En la vista simplemente das a tus controles estos `ng-model`

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns"> => esto iterara 4 veces por ejm:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[column.tipo]" />
    <select>
        <option value="mayor">Mayor que</option>
        <option value="menor">Menor que</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="" />
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="getValues()" />
```

Y para obtener el valor de todos los `checkboxs` pero ver cuales fueron checkeados o no puedes :

```
$scope.getValues = function(){
   console.log($scope.modelo_dinamico);
}
```

Esto retornara :

```
tipo_1 : false,
tipo_2 : true,
tipo_3 : true
```

**EDICION**

Como en este caso son mas inputs los que deben llevar modelos dinamicos podria ser asi :

```
$scope.modelo_dinamico = [];
$scope.objeto = {'tipo' : '', checkbox : '' , select : '', input : ''};
angular.forEach($scope.columns, function(columna, index){
     $scope.objeto.tipo = columna.tipo;
     $scope.objeto.checkbox = true;
     $scope.objeto.select = "menor";
     $scope.objeto.input = "Hola";
     $scope.modelo_dinamico[index] = $scope.objeto;
     $scope.objeto = {};
});
```

Que hago aqui? Aparte de definir un arreglo vacio, defino UN TIPO DE OBJETO que contiene todos los inputs que deseo agregar dinamicamente. En este caso un `<checkbox>`, `<select>` y un `<input>`. **¿ Por que el valor de index?**, Simple, vi en tu ejemplo que por cada dato que modificas, se agrega un objecto `{}` con los valores anteriormente editamos, con `index` se crea un objeto unico por cada elemento que se repite (con tu formato)

Recorro el arreglo y le doy valores por defecto (podrian ser vacios si asi lo quieres) Y en la vista los muestro asi :

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[$index].checkbox" />
    <select ng-model="modelo_dinamico[$index].select">
        <option value="mayor">Mayor que</option>
        <option value="menor">Menor que</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[$index].input" />
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="getValues()" />
</body>
```

La funcion `getValues()`

```
$scope.getValues = function(){
   console.log($scope.modelo_dinamico);
}
```

Esto imprimira :

```
Array[4] :
   0 : Object
      checkbox : true,
      input : "Hola",
      select : "menor",
      tipo : "tipo_1"
   1 : Object
      checkbox : false,
      input : "Texto de cambio",
      select : "mayor",
      tipo : "tipo_2"
   2 : Object
      checkbox : false,
      input : "Texto de cambio 2",
      select : "menor",
      tipo : "tipo_3"
   3 : Object
      checkbox : true,
      input : "Sin texto",
      select : "menor",
      tipo : "tipo_4"
```

```js
angular.module('mySuperApp', [])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.columns = [
      {name : 'Columna 1', tipo : 'tipo_1'},
      {name : 'Columna 2', tipo : 'tipo_2'},
      {name : 'Columna 3', tipo : 'tipo_3'},
      {name : 'Columna 4', tipo : 'tipo_4'}
  ];
  
  $scope.modelo_dinamico = [];
  $scope.objeto = {'tipo' : '', checkbox : '' , select : '', input : ''};
  angular.forEach($scope.columns, function(columna, index){
     $scope.objeto.tipo = columna.tipo;
     $scope.objeto.checkbox = true;
     $scope.objeto.select = "menor";
     $scope.objeto.input = "Hola";
     $scope.modelo_dinamico[index] = $scope.objeto;
     $scope.objeto = {};
  });
  
  $scope.getValues = function(){
    console.log($scope.modelo_dinamico);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Popups
    </title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body class="padding" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="column in columns">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[$index].checkbox"/>
   <select ng-model="modelo_dinamico[$index].select">
          <option value="mayor">Mayor que</option>
          <option value="menor">Menor que</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" ng-model="modelo_dinamico[$index].input"/>
  </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="getValues()" /><br><br>
    {{modelo_dinamico | json}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Te dejo un [codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/oYyNNa) para que lo veas funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

quizás haciendo un array con con objetos ej:

`var list=[
{id:0,name:'mayor'},
{id:1,name:'medio mayor'},
{id:2,name:'medio menor'},
{id:3,name:'menor'}
];`

luego:

`<div ng-repeat="l in list">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model=""/>
 <select>
        <option value="l.id">{{l.name}}</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" ng-model=""/>
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="getValues()" />`

Luego al button le das una funcion que revise los check box que esten con checked.

Tambien te dejo este link que hacen algo parecido aunque mucho mas bonito:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474671/angular-ng-repeat-checkbox-from-resource-and-set-checked